# Dakota Optimizer - plot objective functions in real-time

Tags: optimization, software

I am using the [Dakota Optimizer](http://dakota.sandia.gov/software.html).
I have 50+ variables, 50+ constraints and more than one objective function.
Independent of the actual optimizer used, or the output selected:
Is there a way to plot the objective functions while the optimizer is running?

Dakota offers a graphical output, but this shows a combined objective function - not each objective function individually. Furthermore, with the amount of variables and constraints the standard window/screen is too small for a complete graphical output.

I have the values for each objective function at each iteration because I provide them to the responses file. However, I would like to avoid generating an additional file that stores these values and call an external function to plot from that file.

I am looking for a solution which is part of Dakota.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Dakota User Manual](http://dakota.sandia.gov/docs/dakota/5.3/Users-5.3.pdf), section 14.4 it appears that the quick answer to this question is: **No**
Currently that extent of control over the graphical output is not available.